# Simple layout Math for grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

After reading 8 math courses in hischool and college, I still can't figure this out:

A number of images will be places in a grid (just 1 row high) in my iPhone game. All images are the same size. How do I write the function to place, center and scale them?

Example:

```
If there's only one image:  [        [IMAGE]         ]   - Middle of screen
Two images:                 [   [IMAGE]  [IMAGE]     ]
Three images:               [  [IMAGE][IMAGE][IMAGE  ]
etc...
```

Each image is 100 px wide, and there should be an inset of 10px on left and right.

If there's more then 3 image.. all images need to be scaled down to fit inside the width of the screen (300px with inset)

Thanks

Comment: Is 100 px the max size, or do you want the image to be enlarged if there is extra space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using iOS 6+, I'd definitely suggest looking into using a [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) (you could prob find some [YouTube video tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=uicollectionview+tutorial&oq=uicolle&gs_l=youtube.3.1.0l10.1530.2282.0.3861.7.5.0.2.2.0.157.523.3j2.5.0...0.0...1ac.1.HW5Bn9tmzjo) for it too).  I haven't used them yet myself, but my understanding is that they were created specifically for this scenario.

Comment: If you can't use a UICollectionView, then the process becomes a little more involved.  I can post a second answer with that procedure if someone asks for it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like to me your formula should be something like:
Available space = Screen width - (2 * inset)

Then to figure out how much to size the picture based on the available space you just calculated would be: 
individual pic width = available space / number of pictures

I am not sure if the is what you are looking for, if not please get a little more specific.

Comment: Screen width - (2*inset) won't allow for any spacing between the images, just on the ends.  To get even spacing everywhere, use screenWidth - (imageCount + 1) * inset.